# Question removed, not sure why

Tags: discussion

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25634339/oop-parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-public-t-public/25634373#25634373

Says deleted by author - had an answer too!

Why?

Comment: Because OP clicked the delete button?

Comment: @Mysticial I thought if it had an answer you couldn't do that?

Comment: Only if one of the answers is upvoted does it block self-deletion.

Answer (score 7):

That question deserves to be deleted - it is the result of a simple typo, and questions around these are specifically avoided on Stack Overflow due to their low future value.

So this user has done us a favor by deleting their question. It would have been gone soon enough anyway as there is an off topic close reason for typos:

[image]

Comment: Plus, by self-deleting, the user does us a favor by approaching an ask ban, which would prevent that person from continuing to suck the community dry.